# Add double quotation mark to first word of each line

Tags: r, vim

I have an R file of results, such as below:

```
filename totalvar result runtime
file1  100 0 20.45
file2  400 4 4.50  
...
filen  200 1 2.00
```

Some of the filename contains weird characters so I have to add quotations to it. What is the easiest way to use VIM for adding quotation marks to first word of each line?
Something like

```
filename totalvar result runtime
"file1"  100 0 20.45
"file2"  400 4 4.50  
...
"filen"  200 1 2.00
```

Comment: what have you tried so far,.. I can tell you macros recording for one.

Comment: My first attempt was doing something like :%s/$1/\"$1\"/g (where $1 represent the first word the line) but how to capture first word of each line? Sorry new to vim.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a `:substitute` command and matching the first word by a sequence of non-blank characters:

```
:2,$s/\S\+/"&"/
```

The `2,$` performs the substitution starting on line 2 and going through the end of the file.

The `\S\+` matches a sequence of non-whitespace characters. It will match the leftmost one and the longest one possible, which corresponds to the first word in each line.

The `&` on the replacement side is substituted for the match itself, so `"&"` will surround it in double quotes.

---

**UPDATE:** You can generalize this to quote the *k*th word on a line by matching *k-1* words before it.

For example, to quote the 4th word:

```
:%s/\(\S\+\s\+\)\{3}\zs\S\+/"&"/
```

Here the `\(...\)` defines a group of non-whitespace followed by whitespace, the `\{3}` matches 3 of those and the `\zs` marks the beginning of the actual match, so only that part will be replaced.

The net effect is that you're quoting the 4th word of lines that have 4 or more words.

Comment: Thanks. Also for the detailed explanation of the commands. Is there a way to generalize it to quotation mark "kth word" in the line. i.e, kth \S\+

Comment: @Pushpa Updated the answer to include a general method to quote the *k*th word of a line!

Answer (score 3):

Record it for one line, using the following keys (with the cursor at the start of the first line):

`(Esc)qai"(Esc)ea"(Esc)j0q`

Then you can write NumberOfLines@a example: `100@a` for a 100 line you want the first word of each to be within "".

Comment: Was helpful. Thanks.